# How can I detect mouse movement with python inside of a game with cursor locked to the center of the screen?

Tags: python

I want to make a bot that can detect if my mouse is moving left or right in a game. Unfortunately, most games such as ROBLOX, Minecraft, or GTA have the cursor locked in the center of the screen making most mouse-movement libraries insufficient for this task.

I have tried libraries such as pynput, pyautogui, mouse, and even some of ctypes but nothing is working. Here is a script I have tried using ctypes:

```
import ctypes
import time

SM_CXSCREEN = 0
SM_CYSCREEN = 1

user32 = ctypes.windll.user32
screen_width = user32.GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN)
screen_height = user32.GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN)
center_x, center_y = screen_width // 2, screen_height // 2

user32.SetCursorPos(center_x, center_y)

def get_mouse_pos():
    class POINT(ctypes.Structure):
        _fields_ = [("x", ctypes.c_long), ("y", ctypes.c_long)]
    point = POINT()
    user32.GetCursorPos(ctypes.byref(point))
    return point.x, point.y

def move_mouse(x, y):
    user32.SetCursorPos(x, y)

while True:
    mouse_x, _ = get_mouse_pos()

    if mouse_x < center_x:
        direction = "left"
    elif mouse_x > center_x:
        direction = "right"
    else:
        direction = "center"

    print("Mouse is moving", direction)

    move_mouse(center_x, center_y)

    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Could anyone please provide a script to solve this issue? Thank you in advance!